# Python multiprocessing with iterable and multiple arguments

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Using multiprocessing, I want to pass an iterable and multiple arguments:

a) to a function running on n_core cpu
b) yield (or return) n_core results at a time
c) in any order of completion

```
from multiprocessing import Pool 

def func(iterable, args):
    this, that, other = args[0], args[1], args[2]

    for s in iterable:
        return ' '.join([s, this, that, other])        

def main():
    iterable = ['abc', 'bcd', 'cde', 'def', 'efg', 'fgh', 'ghi', 'hij']
    args = ['this', 'that', 'other']
    n_core = 2

    p = Pool(n_core)
    for r in p.imap_unordered(func, iterable, args):
        print(r)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The expected results are:

> ```
> "abc this that other"
> "bcd this that other"
> "cde this that other"
> "def this that other" 
> "efg this that other" 
> "fgh this that other"
> "ghi this that other" 
> "hij this that other"
> ```

What is the correct way to make this work?

Secondly, would concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor be a better option for this problem?

Comment: You are trying to call func once for each item in your iterable. `func` should expect a single item as input, and not the whole iterable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a `new_iterable` that combines the values in `iterable` with `args`:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def func(args):
    iterable, this, that, other = args[0], args[1][0], args[1][1], args[1][2]
    return ' '.join([iterable, this, that, other])

def main():
    iterable = ['abc', 'bcd', 'cde', 'def', 'efg', 'fgh', 'ghi', 'hij']
    args = ['this', 'that', 'other']
    new_iterable = ([x, args] for x in iterable)
    n_core = 2

    p = Pool(n_core)
    for r in p.imap_unordered(func, new_iterable):
        print(r)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Output**

```
abc this that other
bcd this that other
cde this that other
def this that other
efg this that other
fgh this that other
ghi this that other
hij this that other
```

This solution uses a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) to create a new iterable that combines the entries from `iterable` with the desired `args`. You can also use a [generator function](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/functional.html#generators) to do the same thing.

**Update:** I modified `func` to produce the expected results that you mentioned in the comments and added to your question.

Comment: Thanks ... this is very cool. But, the results should be: "abc this that other", "bcd this that other", "cde this that other", and so on.

Comment: Ah. The "for s in iterable" should be removed to leave just "return ' '.join([iterable, this, that, other])". This now works. Will wait for other responses and then accept. Again, thanks.

Comment: @HenryThornton: I updated the answer to produced the expected results.

Answer (score 2):

The code in the question seems wrong. `func` should expect a single item and not the whole iterable.

Instead of:

```
def func(iterable, args):
    this, that, other = args[0], args[1], args[2]

    for s in iterable:
        return ' '.join([s, this, that, other])
```

You may use:

```
def func(item, args):
    this, that, other = args[0], args[1], args[2]
    return ' '.join([item, this, that, other])
```

Apart from this error `imap_unordered` does not accept more than one argument.

This code would do what you expect:

```
try:
    from itertools import izip
except ImportError:  # Python 3 built-in zip already returns iterable
    izip = zip

from itertools import repeat
from multiprocessing import Pool

def func_star_single(func_item_args):
    """Equivalent to:
       func = func_item_args[0]
       item = func_item_args[1]
       args = func_item_args[2:]
       return func(item,args[0],args[1],...)
    """
    return func_item_args[0](*[func_item_args[1]] + func_item_args[2])


def func(item, args):
    this, that, other = args[0], args[1], args[2]
    return ' '.join([item, this, that, other])    


def main():
    iterable = ['abc', 'bcd', 'cde', 'def', 'efg', 'fgh', 'ghi', 'hij']
    args = ['this', 'that', 'other']
    n_core = 2

    p = Pool(n_core)
    for r in p.imap_unordered(func_star_single, izip(repeat(func), iterable, repeat(list([args])))):
        print(r)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```